# Mongoid Rails update error for documents having embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.2, mongoid5

I have a model called User. User embeds_many posts.

For User records having embedded posts, whenever I try to update any other field, I am getting the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for false:FalseClass
```

I am using update as follows

```
user = User.find('56da7307421aa90ca4000000')
user.update(likes: 12)
```

If I remove `embeds_many :posts` from User model file, the above update query works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured out the issue myself. The issue was the result of bad written association. It has to be like given below. But I had missed the `embedded_in` relationship inside Post model.

```
class User
  embeds_many :posts
end

class Post
  embedded_in :user
end
```

Writing `embedded_in :user` inside Post model solved the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept your own answer tomorrow.